# How to Execute List of Tasks?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, task

I have a list of `List<System.Security.Claim>` and I want to add each claim asynchronously.  I am curious how to run all tasks and set a `boolean` to use later to ensure all tasks have been run.

```
foreach (var claim in claims)
{
    claimTasks.Add(UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, claim));   
}

claimResultSucceeded = Task.WhenAll(claimTasks).IsCompleted;
```

I have also tried this:

```
foreach (var claim in claims)
{
    claimTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, claim)));   
}

claimResultSucceeded = Task.WhenAll(claimTasks).IsCompleted;
```

**Edit:** As you can see in the photo below, the tasks are hitting a faulted state:

> {"A second operation started on this context before a previous
>   asynchronous 
>       operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations
>       have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance 
>       members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."}

[image]

Comment: What do you expect `.IsCompleted` to do? Please state what you expect your code to do and what you observe it doing.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen .IsCompleted should contain the result of true or false once all tasks have been executed.  I updated the question with more details.

Comment: @user1477388 No, it returns whether or not the task has currently completed, and it returns that immediately.

Comment: @Servy, then per Mike's answer below, how can I check to see that all tasks have completed successfully?

Comment: @user1477388 Start by looking at the documentation for `Task`, It explains exactly how you can go about doing that.

Comment: @Servy Thanks but I've already been there and I came up with the solution above.  It doesn't work, so I came here with questions.  Is that ok?

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to spend some more time there reading through the various operations in more detail, and looking more closely at the remarks.  It's pretty clear about what this operation does, and what other operations it has.

Comment: You should use `Task.WhenAll(...)` and then wait for the task that it returns to complete. You're just checking if it has currently returned, which it likely hasn't.

Comment: Basically: `await Task.WhenAll(claimTasks);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure? Task.WhenAll will take a set of Task (and so accept any return value from those tasks) and return a new Task which you may wait to complete, just as you have suggested?

I've put the following code sample together, which is basically what you've shown (with a bit of nonsense data to ensure that there was enough to compile) -

```
static async void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Declare some references to work with (this data is rubbish, it's just here so
    // that everything compiles)
    var userManager = new UserManager<User, Key>(null);
    var user = new User();
    var claims = new List<Claim>();
    var claimTasks = new List<Task<IdentityResult>>();

    // This is basically the code that appears in the question - it compiles fine
    foreach (var claim in claims)
    {
        claimTasks.Add(userManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, claim));
    }

    // WhenAll returns a single task that will be completed when all of the individual
    // claims tasks have completed
    var claimResults = await Task.WhenAll(claimTasks);

    // When this happens, you should be able to look at each of the IdentityResults
    // instances in the claimResults array to ensure they all succeeded
    // Note: I'm presuming a little here since I'm not too familiar with these types, but
    // it seems reasonable that the Succeeded flag on each IdentityResult should indicate
    // whether or not it was successfully retrieved
    var allRequestsSucceeded = claimResults.All(c => c.Succeeded);
}

// This struct and class have no purpose other than making the code compile
public struct Key : IEquatable<Key>
{
    public bool Equals(Key other) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public class User : IUser<Key>
{
    public Key Id
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get {  throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can see in the photo I just added, the code will compile and execute; however, the tasks are never run.  They remain in a faulted state because an error is occurring (I didn't realize this before).

Comment: Ah, I see. Your question originally said that it was a return type issue you were having - IdentityResult where you wanted a bool, so I presumed that you code didn't compile. I'm going to tweak my answer (for future posterity), taking into account the comment by @Lasse V. Karlen which is completely correct (and I can't believe I didn't notice originally!) that "IsCompleted" is the wrong thing to check and that the Task returned by WhenAll should be awaited. When that has completed, all of your child tasks have completed (whether they've succeeded or failed may be a different matter).

Answer (score 1):

Your new error is coming from Entity Framework. You can only have one async operation per db context instance. Just do this:

```
foreach (var claim in claims)
{
    var result = await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, claim);
    if (result.Succeded == false) {
        // Handle the error
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
Incorporated [@Dan Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813189/dan-roberts) advice.

Comment: With this, how can I check to see that all tasks have completed successfully?

Comment: If you tweak this to "var addClaimResult = await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, claim);" inside the loop then you can check "addClaimResult.Succeeded" each call and set a flag if any of them say that they didn't succeed. This approach won't do the work in parallel but it will be async in that a thread won't be tied up while each AddClaimAsync call is being processed, which is valuable. I think that Mike probably knows these identity classes much better than I and this answer may be better than mine (so it deserves, and is getting, an up vote from me).

Comment: Good catch @DanRoberts, I edited to add checking the result.